# How to rewrite a database subquery into a join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying rewrite this subquery into a join.  I have read the other questions on SO but cant get this one working.

```
create table job (
  emplid int, 
  effdt date,
  title varchar(100),
  primary key (emplid, effdt)
);

insert into job set emplid=1, effdt='2010-01-01', title='Programmer';
insert into job set emplid=1, effdt='2011-01-01', title='Programmer I';
insert into job set emplid=1, effdt='2012-01-01', title='Programmer II';

insert into job set emplid=2, effdt='2010-01-01', title='Analyst';
insert into job set emplid=2, effdt='2011-01-01', title='Analyst I';
insert into job set emplid=2, effdt='2012-01-01', title='Analyst II';

#Get each employees current job:
select *
from job a
where a.effdt=
    (select max(b.effdt) 
    from job b
    where b.emplid=a.emplid);
```

Results:

```
+--------+------------+---------------+
| emplid | effdt      | title         |
+--------+------------+---------------+
|      1 | 2012-01-01 | Programmer II |
|      2 | 2012-01-01 | Analyst II    |
+--------+------------+---------------+
```

I would like to rewrite the query into a join, without a subquery.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing this as a `join` is perhaps a bit counterintuitive.  The idea is to use a `left outer join` and include in the condition that `b.effdt > a.effdt`.  This condition will match rows except when `a.effdt` takes on the maximum value.  The query can then filter for these using a `where`:

```
select a.*
from job a left outer join
     job b
     on  b.emplid = a.emplid and
         b.effdt > a.effdt
where b.effdt is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered rewriting your schema?
If you are able to, it might be better to have a history or log table that has entries for when the effective date was changed, for which employee ID and what the previous title was. That way you would just query the actual table and get the results that you want.
This can be achieved by using triggers for whenever a row in the database is changed, then everything is handled at the database level.